# Which network interface is used if they are both the default gateway?

Tags: linux, networking, routing

In this example below on my Linux machine, I have an Ethernet and Wifi interface established.  Here is the route output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 mlan0
default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 mlan0
```

Without any further modifications, which interface would the kernel use to send data out on the 192.168.1.x network?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/network-interface-preference?rq=1) question.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply test any address with the `ip route get` command (see `man ip-route`). Eg

```
$ ip route get 192.168.1.99
192.168.1.99 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.0
```